# delete duplicate node and their relations in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The cypher query MATCH `(n:BusinessBranch) RETURN n` returns all the nodes and I want to delete the duplicate nodes and their relations based on the property `address`. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to just delete the duplicates or do you want to merge them into one instance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[UPDATED]

1. To delete **all** `BusinessBranch` nodes that share the same `address` property value (which would also require deleting all their relationships):

   ```
   MATCH (b:BusinessBranch)
   WITH b.address AS address, COLLECT(b) AS branches
   WHERE SIZE(branches) > 1
   FOREACH (n IN branches | DETACH DELETE n);
   ```

   This query collects all the `BusinessBranch` nodes that have the same address, filters for collections that have more than one branch, and then uses `DETACH DELETE` on all the branches in the resulting collections (which will delete the branches *and* their relationships).
2. To delete **all but one** of the duplicate nodes, you *could* do this:

   ```
   MATCH (b:BusinessBranch)
   WITH b.address AS address, COLLECT(b) AS branches
   WHERE SIZE(branches) > 1
   FOREACH (n IN TAIL(branches) | DETACH DELETE n);
   ```

   *However*, in this case you should first take a look at the APOC procedure [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/#merge-nodes), which is more appropriate for most use cases.

Comment: Will it not delete all the nodes from branches? In that case, If say you have a business "XYZ" two times, after running this query you will be left with 0 entries of "XYZ" and i think one entry from the two should be left.

Comment: The question did not state that it wanted to keep one of the nodes. As my original answer stated, it would delete all the duplicate nodes. However, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @cybersam

Comment: Very good answer Thanks a million @cybersam